# Converting a String decimal to a float or double in Swift?

Tags: ios, string, swift, double

I'm trying to convert a String such as "3.9" to a Float value in Swift that will be represented as 3.9 (which can then be used in calculations).
I'm running into issues here as the conversion doesn't seem to be going right, my code looks like this:

```
var a:Float = (lastNumber as NSString).floatValue
var b:Float = (answerField!.text! as NSString).floatValue
if (operatorLabel?.text == "+"){
      println(a)
   }
```

I'm trying to make a basic calculator app, as you can see. However, when I print the "a" value, it shows up as an error (11db) and I'm not sure how to approach this issue. Any thoughts? I'm thinking right now that I might be having a problem because the period in "3.9" isn't being converted to a decimal point, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Are you sure that lastNumber is "3.9". Your code should work if it is... just tested it in a playground to be 100%.

Comment: I googled it, and it seems like this might be an issue because I'm using Xcode6 beta6. Are you using that as well?

Comment: I am using 6.1.1 from the app store. Good thing you found the problem though.

Answer (score 0):

It's even simpler.

```
let s = "3.9"
let a = Float(s)
```

Watch out for force unwrapping - and don't make outlet optional.

```
if let st = answerField.text {
   b = Float(s)
}
```

Comment: outlets have to be optional, always. An implicitly unwrapped optional is no better than forced unwrapping.

Comment: @Sulthan In the case of outlets, many people (including me) would argue that implicitly unwrapped optionals are fine.

Comment: @TimVermeulen I completely agree but consider the sentence "don't make outlet optional and watch for force unwrapping". That does not makes sense because implicitly unwrapped optional is an optional and always forces unwrapping.

Comment: Oh, I interpreted "don't make outlet optional" as either an explicit optional or an implicitly unwrapped optional. I agree with you though.

Comment: blah blah fishcake. Pedantry aside, I'm warning against answerField.text! You cannot assume there is data there. As for the outlet, you will find out rather quickly if it is nil.